# PostGIS ST_Within processing speed

Tags: sql, qgis-3, postgis-2.0, postgresql-9.6

I've created an SQL script that selects a given set of polygons ("v_rag_RenouvellementClaim") that are completeley within a specified buffer ("v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer") using PostGIS `ST_Within`. The code works but is very slow to display as a table or as a layer in QGIS 3 (over 3 minutes). The result outputs just under 20000 records.
Is there a more efficient way to get this to display/run?

I'm using QGIS 3, PostgreSQL 9.6 and PostGIS 2.3

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "GestionPropriete_Staging_RnvlmntClaims"."v_rag_RecClaim_Within4500mBuffer_25000" as
SELECT 
    "v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer".tit_no || '_' || "v_rag_RenouvellementClaim".tit_no as uid, --concatenates the Allocation Claim number to the Reipient Claim number as UID
    "v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer".tit_no as "Alloc_Claim",
    "v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer".geom,
    "v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer"."1_renewal_cre_cu" as "Alloc_Credit",
     "v_rag_RenouvellementClaim".tit_no  as "Rec_Claim",
     "v_rag_RenouvellementClaim"."1_renewal_cre_cu",
     ABS("v_rag_RenouvellementClaim"."1_renewal_cre_cu")  as "Rec_abs_Credit_1stRenw" -- returns the absolute value of the 1st renewal credit value.
    FROM "GestionPropriete"."v_rag_RenouvellementClaim", "GestionPropriete"."v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer"
        WHERE "v_rag_RenouvellementClaim"."1_renewal_cre_cu" < 0 AND -- selects the values where the 1st renewal cost is less than 0
            st_within("v_rag_RenouvellementClaim".geom, "v_rag_RenouvellementClaimGrtr25000_Buffer".geom)
```

Comment: do you have spatial indexes?

Comment: Good point, I've made sure the source data set has a spatial index.  Would the fact that this script references two views rather than actual tables have an impact on the load times?

Comment: Try running `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers) ` on this query to see the bottleneck.

Comment: You could also use a materialised view rather than a view if this is only processed occasionally.